# .NET Core (OS X) - How to add self-signed certificate, bound to Kestrel for alternative name of localhost?

Tags: macos, ssl, asp.net-core, https, kestrel

I need to serve an ASP.NET Core (2.1) app from the local machine using an alternative name of the localhost.

I created an entry in the /etc/hosts file:

> 127.0.0.1  localh0st

and I also modified the runtime configuration of the web application (Rider Debug Configuration) to use this hostname in the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable.

I can start the app and access it in the browser via HTTPS but I get the certificate error because the certificate common name is `localhost` and not `localh0st`. This is expected.

I want to be able to load the site without warnings. For this I *believe* I have to take the following steps (which I don't know how to achieve):

1. Create a self-signed certificate for this new hostname
2. Place this certificate in the OS X's keychain and trust it
3. Instruct Kestrel to use this particular certificate and not the `localhost` one.

I am not sure **these are the steps**, and **how to achieve them**.